# Obscure late 80s british, fantasy tv show featuring ye olde curiosity shoppe.

Tags: story-identification

My brain is wracked and I can't find it anywhere online. The show came on late at night once a week and had a young man and pretty woman whom would investigate ghosts and spirits and stuff like that. They would hang out with and get knowledge from an older, gray-haired man who owned "Ye Olde Curiosity Shoppe".

Comment: dude! that's it! My memory was off a bit. Thank you very much. this has been on my mind for years.

Comment: If you've lost access to your account, and it appears as though you have (thanks, OpenID), you should follow [these instructions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20528/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-account); then you'll be able to accept Sean's answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be "[Friday the 13th: the Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th:_The_Series)"?

> An antiques dealer named Lewis Vendredi (played by R.G. Armstrong; "Vendredi" means "Friday" in French) has made a deal with the Devil to sell cursed antiques out of his shop, "Vendredi's Antiques", in exchange for wealth, magic powers, and immortality. In the show's first episode ("The Inheritance"), he rebels against the Devil and breaks the deal. The Devil kills Vendredi and claims his soul for breaking the deal.
>
> After Lewis' death, his shop is inherited by his niece, Micki Foster (played by Louise Robey) and her cousin by marriage, Ryan Dallion (played by John D. LeMay). They decide not to keep the store, and sell off many of the cursed antiques before being stopped by Jack Marshak (played by Chris Wiggins). Jack was Lewis' friend, a retired world-traveller and occultist who originally collected many of the antiques for Vendredi before they became cursed.

They rename the shop "Curious Goods", which is similar to your title, and Jack might be the older man you're thinking of. It was not a British show, but they did broadcast it in the UK, ostensibly as *Friday's Curse*.

[image: The three protagonists]

Comment: I remember watching this show as a kid, it was fairly dark for the time period.